# Projections to orthogonal complements of conditional expectations

Tags: oa.operator-algebras

For a conditional expectation from a C^* algebra A to a subalgebra B, we can form a positive projection $P:A\to A$ with image equal to $B$. Question: is $Id - P:A\to A$ a positive map?

Comment: One immediate obstruction:  if  $B\neq A$ and $P$ is unital then $\text{id} - P\neq  0$ but sends the identity to 0 so $\text{id} -P$ is not positive.  On the other hand there are positive examples like $A \oplus A \to A\oplus 0$ but I don't know a complete answer for the general case

Comment: This sounds like the answer. Thanks. I can't see how to make it an official answer...